# Searching for a Custom Forms

Tags: customization, netsuite

I have a question about working with CustomForms. I would like to implement a function/search in SuiteScript that would search for CustomForm by Name instead of ID. Any suggestions?

Comment: 1. I don't think you can search forms as a record type.
2. I don't understand why you would do this.

If you can explain what you're trying to accomplish, I will try to suggest a solution.

Comment: We are facing pretty big issues with deploying new features/modifications to Production Environment.

Comment: For example we are doing some changes to Support Cases. We have owner own Custom Form, that being modified. The problem is that we have 24/7 Support and we dont like the idea of telling them to stop Solving Cases because of our deployment and testing. So I came up with an idea to create a duplicate Form of the currently used one and make changes on the Copy. When the copy would be deployed to Production, nobody would notice, because it is not set as Default. Testers would verify functionality on Production Environment and then we would just switch Modified Custom Form to be default.

Comment: Unfortunately, there are also few scheduled SuiteScripts, that are checking mailbox every few minutes and creating SupportCases automatically - so they use a certain CustomForm ID, but if we create new Custom Form, it will have new ID. So I thought there could be a way to get the ID dinamically using some parameter that can be unified - like Name. So we dont need to change IDs in Script every time we would do modification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure I 100% get the problem, but see if this doen't help:

1. Remove code from email to support case script that sets field "customForm".
2. Create specific role for user used to create the cases - don't assign a generic role, like "administrator".
3. In code for script, specify the role you created in #2 for the login/authentication.
4. Now, you can flip back and forth between forms from the NetSuite UI by making the needed form the default for the role you created in #2.

All other users will be unaffected, and you won't have to modify the script going forward, except if you have new functionality to add to it.

The other option is to always make the script use the standard case form. That way, you'll never really need to change it. The standard form will contain all custom fields and all standard fields. The only thing you would then need to control is the preferred form by role.

Comment: This one seems promising. I tried to use that in SandBox and it seems it might be working fine :) Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the development in sandbox environment and test it there completely before doing the production deployment. You can ask your support team to stop for few minutes while doing the deployment and then do a quick smoke test if possible.